# In LMAX disruptor,How producer knows consumer has finished the job

Tags: disruptor-pattern

Is there anyway consumers inform producer that any particular event is processed successfully ?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly no, and given that the disruptor is intended decouple processing doing so would negate all the performance gains which it provides.

Answer (score 0):

You can wire this up, if you like.  Something like

```
class MyEvent {
  String payload;
  Runnable onComplete;
}
```

Then have your event handler/consumer/whatever run onComplete after it handles the payload.  Replace runnable with a Future or any other thing you might like, but this pattern works best for asynchronous things (maybe the runnable sets a done flag in your UI?)

Disruptor tends to be a poor fit for things where the caller needs to block for the result.

Answer (score 0):

could you not just maintain counters in your producer(s) and consumer(s), producer(s) increment counter before publishing, consumer(s) increment counter after processing, then have the producer compare the `produced_count` with the `consumed_count`?